# Enter Network Credentials

Tags: networking, windows-10, shared-folders

When connecting to a shared folder on the network, it is asking for network credentials (username and password), even though I have password protected sharing disabled. What is especially odd is that we can type in random text as the username and password and it works fine.

Is this an error? If not, how can I enter in the fake credentials from a batch file?

I'm using Windows 10 home (latest update). I disabled password protected sharing in sharing options in the control panel.

Comment: Have you turned off password protected sharing on the target/server device? Have you rebooted afterward?

Comment: “Even though I have password protected sharing disabled”. Yes.

Comment: Please edit the question with the server OS, sharing method, how you disabled password protected sharing, and the client OS.

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure how exactly you disabled the "password protected sharing". But what should solve the problem is to allow read (and write, depending on you're goal) for everyone (which I assume you did correctly) and also change the security settings for everyone:

[image]

The access via command line I think this is it (but I'm not 100%):

```
\\<server>\<sharename> /USER:<domain>\<username> <password>
```

Comment: Hmm okay, for some of the files I can’t do that I can give read but not write. Would the net use command work?

Comment: @MarkDodsons In this case you don't have the right to access/change the the security settings. You need to log on as a user having enough rights, or change the ownership. If you know why you can not change them on the GUI I can tell you the right command (or just look it up yourself there are about a million of howtos on the web), otherwise it will be a guessing game.

Comment: No lol I have access to the host computer physically.

Comment: But some files I don’t want users who connect to be able to write too, but view without having to type credentials.

Comment: then unfortunately I don't understand you're problem... :S could you please be a little bit more specific, maybe an example?

Comment: When I type \\computerhostname\ on another pc I want to have instant access to all files (except a few that are read only). However, atm it is asking for credentials. These credentials can be anything (doesn’t have to be valid credentials you can just type 1234,1234) and then it works.

Comment: I added it to my answer

Comment: Thanks, will I have to do this every time or only once?

Comment: The GUI has a option to save the credentials, so the commend line should have the option as well...  at least try to search for it before asking, it's not hard to find! ; ) it might be /persistent:yes I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Yeah that should be easy to figure out. Thanks for your help.

Comment: sure thing...  it might be /persistent:yes I'm not 100% sure. maybe i confuse it with another command. Let me know if it worked or not.