# Network Share Folder

Tags: windows-10, network-shares, shared-folders, credentials

I'm having this issue with my shared folder that it keeps asking for credentials, where I have already disabled  it.
The folder I want to access its located in one VM that I have locally here (Hyper-V).
I follow all the instructions to able the share folder, and also for disabling the credentials, but none of them worked.

To enable the shared folder, I followed this steps below:

https://computerinfobits.com/how-to-enable-file-sharing/

Most of the pages I visited, they have the same steps. I believe I did it correct because it asks for passowrd.
Also, on the step 5 of this guide, it is showing how to disable the crendentials, which is the same steps I found in the most of the web sites I had a look, but still got that annoying screen.

Is there anything else that can be done? Am I missing something?

Also, have checked this post, and it didn't work.

[Enter Network Credentials](https://superuser.com/questions/1362240/enter-network-credentials)

Cheers

Comment: Ugh. Been a while since I’ve operated anything like this but it is certainly more complicated than the article you linked. You CANNOT access file shares without a password on windows. That is called anonymous access, it’s a huge security risk and it has to be allowed in the registry or group policy. Something else that *might* work is using the same username and password on both computers. Why not simply type in the password and use the option to save it for later?

Comment: https://petri.com/enable-anonymous-access-to-a-windows-server-file-share/

Answer (score 0):

**1. Open Credential Manager**

[image]

**2. Click on "Add a windows credential"**

[image]

**3. Add the credentials to your server**

[image]